# Getting error message when trying to add new COM+ application in Windows 8 through Component services.

Tags: windows, com+

Step 1: Run comexp.msc
Step 2: Component services -> computers -> my computer -> right click on COM+ Application, select new application
Step 3: try to create a empty server application with interactive user

After finish, getting error **!["An error occurred while processing the last operation...The event log may contain additional troubleshooting"]**

Found event ID 7031 in event logs, 
Event ID 7031 : **"The COM+ system application terminated unexpectedly.."**

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling McAfee Security scan temporarily until COM+ applications are successfully added, resolved this issue !